# UITabBarController Programmatically

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I'm facing a problem with my UITabBarController.
I'm really sure that I did the same which was described here, but it is not working properly:
https://medium.com/@ITZDERR/uinavigationcontroller-and-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically-swift-3-d85a885a5fd0

Could you please have a look.
TabBarController:

```
import UIKit
class TabBarController: UITabBarController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

//        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

```
    self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .white
    self.tabBar.frame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - CGFloat(tabBarHeight)
    self.tabBar.frame.size.height = CGFloat(tabBarHeight)
    
    let homeVC = UIViewController()
    homeVC.title = "Home"
    homeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Home", image: UIImage(systemName: "house.fill"), tag: 0)
    
    let tripHomeVC = TripHomeViewController()
    tripHomeVC.title = "Trips"
    tripHomeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Trips", image: UIImage(systemName: "globe"), tag: 1)
    
    let statsHomeVC = StatisticHomeViewController()
    statsHomeVC.title = "Statistics"
    statsHomeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Statistic", image: UIImage(systemName: "chart.pie.fill"), tag: 2)
    
    let settingsHomeVC = SettingsHomeViewController()
    settingsHomeVC.title = "Home"
    settingsHomeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Settings", image: UIImage(systemName: "gear"), tag: 3)
    
    let controllerArray = [homeVC, tripHomeVC, statsHomeVC, settingsHomeVC]
//        tabBarController.viewControllers = controllerArray


    self.viewControllers = controllerArray.map { UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)}
    
//        view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
  }

}
```

In my HomeController I simply added the TabBar:

```
    //              Setup TabBar
    let tabBarController = TabBarController()
    self.view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
```

The TabBar is shown but not working.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9b40.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating `UITabBarController` inside `UITabBarController` make no sense?

Comment: You're right, my bad. Just changed it, but that change will not solve my problem I think.

Comment: What do you mean by _The TabBar is shown but not working._ what exactly not working? Add screenshot if possible please. And does your `HomeController` is rootViewController?

Comment: Screenshot and improved coding added. My HomeController is not my rootViewController, before you reach to the HomeController, you have to SignIn and this is my rootViewController. So you can see the TabBar is shown, but when you hit the items, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one line

```
tabBarController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

So it becomes

```
let tabBarController = TabBarController()
self.view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
tabBarController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately it makes no difference. The icons are activated, but nothing happens.